# (DirectX11) How to draw a line using multi-thread?

Tags: multithreading, directx-11

I am developing an directx(d3d11) application.
I want to draw a line using multi-thread

I tried to understand directx11 tutorial file(MultithreadedRendering11) , 
still I don't know what to do..

can I get a multi-thread sample code in direct11?

Comment: Direct X runs on graphics hardware - therefore the "multi-threaded" part is already implemented for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try MSDN? ['Introduction to Multithreading in Direct3D11'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Besides, you can find a multithread sample for DX11 in DirectX SDK(\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D11\MultithreadedRendering11). Since D3D12 has stronger support for multithread, I suppose it may be helpful for you to reference this [DX12 multithread sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples), too.

Please let me know if you need any further information.